# Relations between Stirling numbers of the first kind and the second kind

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, stirling-numbers

Denote the Stirling number of the second kind as $S(n,k)$, and the (signed) Stirling number of the first kind as $s(n,k)$. It is known that 
\begin{align}
\sum_{j = 0}^n S(n,j) s(j,k) = \delta_{nk}.
\end{align}

The natural question is, how can we upper and lower bound the following sum in terms of $n$ and $k$:
\begin{align}
\left | \sum_{j = 0}^n S(n,j) s(j,k) p^j \right|, \quad p \in [0,1], n\neq k.
\end{align}

In some sense, it challenges us to give a continuous interpolation for two extreme values of $p = 0$ and $p = 1$, which both lead to the value zero in the sum.